# Disable unit testing generators in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, generator

Does anyone know how to disable the automatic unit test file generation in Rails? Whenever a controller, model or migration is created then it creates the associated files in the test/ directory; I need this disabled.

Also, is it possible to make RPsec take over so that the files are created with RSpec (in the spec/ directory) when a standard rails g model|controller|migration command is performed?

Comment: If you want to disable all parts of the tests from generating you can use `config.generators.test_framework false` in application.rb

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You want something like this in your application.rb

```
config.generators do |g|
    g.test_framework  :rspec, :fixture => false
    g.view_specs      false
    g.helper_specs    false
end
```

More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow

Personally, I use this one:

```
config.generators do |g|
    g.orm             :mongoid
    g.template_engine :haml
    g.test_framework  :rspec, :fixture => false
    g.view_specs      false
    g.helper_specs    false
    g.fixture_replacement :fabrication
end
```

Comment: ...except that should be `:fixture => false`. Rails fixtures are *dangerous* and make your tests brittle and inaccurate. Use factories instead.

Comment: For a Rails engine note this would go into engine.rb

Comment: This doesn't disable test_unit generation for me on Rails 5. If I do ``g.test_framework false`` it just disables rspec generation.

Comment: I was mistaken. Nerian's answer works fine for Rails 5.1, it was just that the system tests (a feature to bake in capybara added in 5.1) showed test_unit being invoked, even though it was actually system tests.

Comment: I still get one file in test/integration/job_test.rb (my class in names job) Is this form the Rspec?

Comment: @Jepzen I had to add `g.integration_tool :rspec` in order to fix that and have rspec handle integration as well.

Comment: Update for RSpec 4.0: `g.test_framework` and `g.integration_tool` will be [provided out-of-the-box](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/be3ae66f25863e05336d7fb54b363a833179aa4c/lib/rspec-rails.rb#L20-L21).

Comment: As of Rails 6, I still get unwanted model specs with that config