# any way to disable fixtures app-wide?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I don't want to use fixtures at all. There is a flag you can use when scaffolding that says don't make fixtures, but sometimes I forget. Is there an app-wide setting I can use to not have to use this flag every time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable unit testing generators in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497668/disable-unit-testing-generators-in-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you're using Rails 3, yes. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow , specifically the `g.test_framework` line in the first example. Setting `:fixture => false` will stop fixture generation.