# How to avoid to generate usefulness stuff in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When i run the command

```
rails g controller admin/inbox
```

Its generate test_unit and helper/test_unit. But i dont want to generate it. how to avoid it during generate controller

```
  create  app/controllers/admin/inbox_controller.rb
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/admin/inbox
  invoke  test_unit
  create    test/functional/admin/inbox_controller_test.rb
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/admin/inbox_helper.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/unit/helpers/admin/inbox_helper_test.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/admin/inbox.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/admin/inbox.css.scss
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497668/disable-unit-testing-generators-in-rails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your workflow by configuring `config/application.rb` like this..

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.orm             :active_record
  g.template_engine :erb
  g.test_framework  :test_unit, :fixture => false
  g.stylesheets     false
end
```

for more details visit http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html.

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you only want to skip the test generation just once, you can do this:

```
rails g controller admin/index --skip-test-framework
```

or

```
rails g controller admin/index --no-test-framework
```

This is covered in [the documentation for Generators::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generators/Base.html).