# Don't generate test automatically in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'm using rspec with Rails 4 and when creating controllers, for example, I always have to pass the "**--no-test-framework**" parameter. Is there a way to not generate these tests by default without needing to explicitly specify it (I often forget and then need to manually delete the generated tests).

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable unit testing generators in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497668/disable-unit-testing-generators-in-rails)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just add the following to `config/application.rb` (within the Application class):

```
config.generators.test_framework false
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add the following to `config/application.rb` to prevent specific specs from generating:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.controller_specs false 
  g.view_specs false
  g.helper_specs false
  g.model_specs false
end
```